# How do you do a multi-tier event for a registration page?

Tags: civievent

I need to insert multiple locations, days, and times. (Fundraiser, symposium, etc.)

Comment: Hi Julia - it is better to give more information than less, for example, are people meant to be able to register for specific locations, or is this more just about the Info page. If you can flesh out the options more I am sure you will get some useful answers.

Comment: Also explain perphaps why you don't want to do the Fundraiser as a separate event to the Symposiun